# CURRENT_DATE no Firebird

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, data, firebird

tudo bem?

Necessito pegar um período de datas maior que 3 anos.
No PostgreSql estava realizando assim:

`SELECT * FROM PEDIDO WHERE DT_EMISSAO > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 YEAR'`

Porém ao tentar executar isso na base do Firebird, não está funcionando, gostaria de saber se o Firebird permite realizar esta mesma operação de forma simples?

Comment: aparece alguma coisa quando não funciona?

Comment: Opa Renato, tranquilo? Cara, ele me retorna dizendo que a função INTERVAL não existe no Firebird. Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei algo semelhante a isso ´´´(select dateadd (-36 month to current_date) from rdb$database)´´´, funcionou, mas não sei se é a forma correta entende?

Comment: vc pode colocar só `dateadd (-36 month to current_date)` ou `dateadd (-3 year to current_date)` no lugar de `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 YEAR'`

Comment: @imex muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -3):

Testei com `CURRENT_DATE-365` e funcionou.